# $(|x_1|+|x_2|+...+|x_n|)$ vs $\sqrt{(|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2+...+|x_n|^2)}$, which is larger and why?

Tags: induction

Actually, I know which is larger. Is there some kind of rule that states that the square root is less or equal to the first expression?

** My tag is probably incorrect **

Comment: Hint: square both numbers.

Comment: Ahmed's answer below uses essentially the same idea, so feel free to accept his answer.

Comment: Ok. What tag shall I use for this post?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2 + 2\sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} |x_i| |x_j| \ge \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2 $$